# How can I manage to update this script

Tags: python, tweepy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# twitterbots/bots/favretweet.py

import tweepy
import logging
from config import create_api
import seacret

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

#stream = tweepy.Stream(seacret.KEY, seacret.SECRET, seacret.TOKEN, seacret.TOKEN_SECRET)

class FavRetweetListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        self.user = api.get_user(screen_name='MyGasAndEnergy1')

    def on_status(self, tweet):
        logger.info(f"Prosessing tweet id {tweet.id}")

        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None or tweet.user.id == self.user.user_id:
            return

        if not tweet.favorite:
            try:
                tweet.favorite()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error on Fav", exc_info=True)

        if not tweet.retweeted:
            try:
                tweet.retweet()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error on vav and retweet", exc_info=True)

        def on_error(self, status):
            logger.error(status)

def main(keywords):
    api = create_api()
    tweets_listener = FavRetweetListener(api)
    #new way to auth
    stream = tweepy.Stream(seacret.KEY, seacret.SECRET, seacret.TOKEN, seacret.TOKEN_SECRET)
    #old way to auto + important tweets_listener for actions
    stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweets_listener)
    stream.filter(track=keywords, languages=["en"])
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(["Python", "Tweepy"])
```

I have older code for editing for my use. But this part I can not figure, because of my noobines. Code is suppose to fav and retweet in twitter if it founds suitable keyword.

New code needs:

```
stream = tweepy.Stream(seacret.KEY, seacret.SECRET, seacret.TOKEN, seacret.TOKEN_SECRET)
```

Old code needs:

```
 tweets_listener = FavRetweetListener(api)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweets_listener)
```

But new tweepy don't work with older `api.auth` method but want all secret tokens to be in `tweepy.Stream()` and that mean that I can not launch rest of my code via `tweets_listener` becauce it wont accept anything more.

How can I continue. I haven't found solution for this after googling or/and can not ask proper questions to move on with this problem.

Tweepy is python module/packet for working twitter-things. This script is originally from realpython.com. Problem is that I don't want to downgrade tweepy.

So I need include FavRetweetListener, but I don't have knowledge how I have to refactor code.

Comment: You need to add way more code to make it easier to answer this question. What is `FavRetweetListener`? What is `api`? What is `tweepy`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @bbb tweepy is a library for the twitter API in Python I believe

Comment: Yes, its external library for twitter api. I tryes to keep up with Twitter's changes. This original code I use, used old version. Twitter want's coders to move to api v2. There is plenty old examples out there and documentation is not very straight for noobies like me.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to tweepy.Cursor and get it working. Thanks to all. Better question next time.

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v1_pagination.html#tweepy.Cursor